# Search Method, If Statement showing several times

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

in the below code im searching for a surname in the lName array, once the surname is not found in the array the else output is showing for each time it is not found going round the loop, how would i go about solving this? if i add a return false statement in the else part it stops the loop after checking the first position of the array.

any help will be appriciated!

```
public boolean search(String StudentlName)
{ 
    boolean found = true;   // set flag to true to begin first pass

    while ( found ==true )
    {
        for (int index = 0; index<lName.length; index ++)
        {
            if (StudentlName.equalsIgnoreCase(lName[index])  )
            {
                System.out.println(course+"\n"+
                "Student ID = \t"+index+"\n"+ 
                unitTitle + "\n" +
                fName[index] + "\n"  + 
                lName[index] + "\n" + 
                Marks[index] + "\n" + "\n" );
                found = false;

                return true;//Stops The Loop once Found used to stop infinite loop
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Student Not Found");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;  
}
```

**If the result is not found this is shown output**

> Student Not Found
>   Student Not Found
>   Student Not Found
>   Student Not Found
>   Student Not Found

Comment: In the future, you should properly format your code before posting it so it's easier for people to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print "Student not found" outside the loop, right before you return false. You only return false once, and by then you know you didn't find the student; no "else" required.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean search(String StudentlName)
{ 
    boolean found = true;   // set flag to true to begin first pass

    while ( found ==true )
    {
    for (int index = 0; index<lName.length; index ++)
    {
        if (StudentlName.equalsIgnoreCase(lName[index])  )
        {
            System.out.println(course+"\n"+
            "Student ID = \t"+index+"\n"+ 
            unitTitle + "\n" +
            fName[index] + "\n"  + 
            lName[index] + "\n" + 
            Marks[index] + "\n" + "\n" );
            found = false;

            return true;//Stops The Loop once Found used to stop infinite loop
        }


    }
    System.out.println("Student Not Found");
    return false;
    }
return true;  
}
```

This will work for you as else part is executing each time you miss the surname you want to search.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, I'm fairly certain that while loop isn't doing any good.  It will always return on it's first iteration, so it's needless.  So having removed found and the while loop, we're left with.

```
public boolean search(String StudentlName)
{ 
    for (int index = 0; index<lName.length; index ++)
    {
        if (StudentlName.equalsIgnoreCase(lName[index])  )
        {
            System.out.println(course+"\n"+
                 "Student ID = \t"+index+"\n"+ 
                 unitTitle + "\n" +
                 fName[index] + "\n"  + 
                 lName[index] + "\n" + 
                 Marks[index] + "\n" + "\n" );
            return true;//Stops The Loop once Found
        }
        //Don't do anything when they aren't equal, except test the next one
    }
    //We checked everything, found nothing, So now print the message.
    System.out.println("Student Not Found");
    return false;
}
```